# Use cdn for Jquery and Css files - overriding Prestashop's default settings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prestashop, cdn

My next question is going to all programmers of Php and developers of prestashop. 
My issue here is that I want to use various CDNs for caching most of my static content such as javascript and css files. 

The php script that I have written so far it is this one but the problem is that I am only redirecting one file to a CDN library. I want some of those files to be cached but not all of them. 
This is my piece of code and so far from the tests that I have been doing with the WebPagetest, it is working.

```
<?php
 class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {
        public function setMedia() {
            parent::setMedia();
            $key = array_search(_PS_JS_DIR_ . 'jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', $this->js_files);
            if ($key !== false)
                $this->js_files[$key] = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js';
        }
    }
```

Moreover, I have added more code to this one in order to cache other jquery files, but no luck (I was getting a 500 internal server error)

```
  <?php

class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {
    public function setMedia() {
        parent::setMedia();
        $key1 = array_search(_PS_JS_DIR_ . 'jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', $this->js_files);
        $key2 = array_search(_PS_JS_DIR_ . 'jquery/plugins/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.js', $this->js_files);
        $key3 = array_search(_PS_JS_DIR_ . 'jquery/plugins/chosen/jquery.chosen.js', $this->js_files);
        if ($key1 !== false)
            $this->js_files[$key1] = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js';

        if($key2 !== false)
            $this->js_files[$key2] = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.1.2/jquery.bxslider.js';

        if($key3 !== false)
            $this->js_files[$key3] = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/0.9.8/chosen.jquery.js'

      }


?>
```

Do you have any ideas about what should I do with my script in order to cache the remaining content that I need? 
Thanks
Orestis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on Prestashop 1.6 (didn't test on 1.5) you can override in class `classes/controller/Controller.php` the method `addJqueryPlugin()`:

```php
/**
 * Adds jQuery plugin(s) to queued JS file list
 *
 * @param string|array $name
 * @param string null $folder
 * @param bool $css
 */
public function addJqueryPlugin($name, $folder = null, $css = true)
{
    if (!is_array($name)) {
        $name = array($name);
    }
    if (is_array($name)) {
        foreach ($name as $plugin) {
            $plugin_path = Media::getJqueryPluginPath($plugin, $folder);
            switch($plugin) {
                case "bxslider":
                    $plugin_path['js'] = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.1.2/jquery.bxslider.js';
                    break;
                case "chosen":
                    $plugin_path['js'] = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/0.9.8/chosen.jquery.js';
                    break;
            }

            if (!empty($plugin_path['js'])) {
                $this->addJS($plugin_path['js'], false);
            }
            if ($css && !empty($plugin_path['css'])) {
                $this->addCSS(key($plugin_path['css']), 'all', null, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The override file nees to go here /public_html/override/classes/controller/Controller.php <br> Right? When I am uploading the file, I am getting a 500 internal server error. Or should I just change the other file and upload it at the same directory?